# LaTeX template for a paper to be submitted to the journal "Applied Artificial Intelligence"

Tags: templates

I want to submit a paper to the journal "Applied Artificial Intelligence". According to the journal's online [instructions for authors](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=uaai20)
, some of the requirements are:

> The main document should be double-spaced as single column text, with
>   one-inch margins on all sides, and all pages should be numbered
>   consecutively. Text should appear in 12-point Times New Roman or other
>   common 12-point font.
>
> Submissions to Applied Artificial Intelligence should follow the style
>   guidelines described in The Chicago Manual of Style (15th ed.).
>   Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary (11th ed.) should be consulted
>   for spelling.
>
> References should be cited parenthetically in the text by author
>   surname(s) and year, in accordance with Chicago Manual of Style
>   guidelines:

Which one latex template is closer than to this style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try anything?

Comment: @egreg Thank you! :)) I don't have the sense especially about double-spaced and looking for a template that close to author's guides in order to start :)

Comment: What about the paper size: Should it be US-Letter, A4, or something else?

Comment: for the spacing you could use `memoir` with the command `\Doublespacing`

Comment: maybe take a look at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-apa-reference-style/jqhskrsqqzfz#.WpQz1eZG1hF where a double-spaced option is also available.

Comment: Do not create a class, do not look for a template,  there is none.  Just use article document class and add what  you need.

Answer (score 5):

The following should be a good start.

First, create a file called `ApplAI.cls`, as follows (observe: capitalization is important):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2015/01/01]
\ProvidesClass{ApplAI}[2018/02/26]

%% Formatting instructions for "Applied Artificial Intelligence", from
%% http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=uaai20

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

% Font: Times Roman clone
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\doublespacing  % or, possibly, "\setstretch{2.0}"

%% Load the "natbib" citation management package.
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
%% Modify appearance of citation call-outs:
\setcitestyle{aysep={}, notesep={, }}
%% Remark: Use "\citep" to create all citation call-outs.

%% Ideally, one would create a bespoke bibliography style. However, 
%% "chicago" may be OK as a starting point.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

%% Place all floats at very end; tables before figures:
\usepackage[tablesfirst]{endfloat} 

%% Only cross-referenced equations should be numbered:
\usepackage[showonlyrefs]{mathtools}

\endinput
```

Load this document class via `\documentclass{ApplAI}` at the start of your main tex file. Next,  be sure to load any other packages you may need in the preamble. Do try to employ either little or no visual formatting anywhere in the document.

The main tex file might look like this:

```
\documentclass{ApplAI} 

%% Load other packages you may need. E.g.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% ...
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


%% Body of document:
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

Some final remarks:

- The journal's instructions are silent about the appearance of sectioning-level headers. Hence, just use `\section`, `\subsection`, etc as you would in any "normal" LaTeX document.
- Use `\eqref` to create cross-references to equations.
- Use only `\citep` to create citation call-outs. Write `\citep[25]{jones:2005}` to create a citation  call-out of the form `(Jones 2005, 25)`. ("25" is the page number.)

Comment: Now  we have another documentclass and template.  :-\

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thanks. Do you think it would be desirable to create a little package and submit it to the CTAN? (I'd still have to create a bibliography style file that fully implements the journal's bibliography-related formatting requirements. The venerable `chicago` style comes close, but it's not an exact match. I'd create the bst file with the `makebst` utility; it shouldn't be too much extra work to do so.) I'd also write a simple "driver" tex file that demonstrates how one should make use of the package's files.

Comment: Isn't providing a template part of the journals work? Looking at the requirements, I'd say they just want the text. I would check with them before doing any work.

Comment: @Johannes_B - You make some very good points! If I find some free time in the next few days, I'll ping the journal and inquire if they're even interested in providing a semi-official template.

Comment: Good idea. You know the process, often the text is converted to XML and from there to html and back to tex.

Comment: AI guys might have something even fancier. :-)